# Flutter Android Debug Bridge (ADB) over different network on VSCODE

Tags: usb, remote-access

I am using VScode for flutter development.

I am also using "ADB Interface for VScode" to debug the coding over the same network wirelessly.

When I am not at home, I remote into my desktop to do some work but I see that most of the ADB only works on the same network.

Does anyone know how to use the ADB over a different network (for example, cellular network on your phone).

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I recognized that my question was poorly worded. I updated the question. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @SteveKim I still think we need more info about how you want to remote to your Flutter dev PC and where the Android device that `adb` is connected to in this scenario. If the `adb debug` device is in your hands while remoting, you should specify details like: is Android device rooted, running Samsung DeX, running the RDP client to get to your Flutter dev PC.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for the reply. I realized I should have one question only. I updated my question in the StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

I think i will just post links to the project called scrcpy and it does it over adb. There is no point in me tutoring about something that has been tutored on the internet.

https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy

https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc/